# SharePoint List - sort column by a conditional format

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a conditionally formatted (JSON) date column that changes color to green if it is completed on time.

Is there a way to select/sort on just the green dates? or is this something that only Excel can do?

Comment: Can you show us the JSON code you used for formatting date column?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap
Sorry I missed your request here.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField <= [$DueDate], 'green', 'red')"
  }
}

Comment: You can only apply sort on actual column values. check my answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you cannot sort/filter based on conditionally formatted value as JSON formatting only customizes the "display" of the list column and does not store/modify the actual value of column.

So while sorting/filtering on column you will have to use the actual values instead of JSON formatted values.

---

If you are trying to apply sorting/filtering on list view, you have to re-create the expressions/logic you used in JSON formatting in list view settings.

Follow below documentations for more information about how to create list views, how to apply sorting/filtering on list views:

1. [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)
2. [Use sorting to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-sorting-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-1e85d6e7-bdb3-4176-b1cb-62c5fbd3ef98)
3. [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4)

Comment: Please **[Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)** and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.